# How to create a custom Knitr hook that replaces chunk output (instead of adding before/after?)

Tags: knitr

I've a blogdown-based Jekyll website and I use knitr from .Rmd to .md. My Jekyll theme has an helper liquid tag for adding a figure and a caption. This is the signature:

```
{% include figure image_path="file.svg" alt="Lorem ipsum" caption="Dolor sic" %}
```

Thus, I would like to change the default output of plot for automatically have that syntax.

I've set this hook:

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(figure = function(before, options, envir) {
    if (!before) {
      ## after a chunk has been evaluated
      name <- paste(options$fig.path, options$label, sep = '')
      message(name)
      return(sprintf("{%% include figure image_path=\"%s\" alt=\"%s\" caption=\"%s\" %%}", name, options$fig.alt, options$fig.cap))

    }
  })
```

but this is the output i get into the .md file:

```
![A scatterplot of the cars data](assets/figures/cars-1.svg){% include figure image_path="assets/figures/cars" alt="Test" caption="A scatterplot of the cars data" %}
```

Two problems here:

- My custom output is added to the default md output for plot, but it should replace it instead (of course the file must be generated on disk)
- The filename. Of course the 'label' is not working, but how to get the filename for the first plot of the chunk (of course I know it doesn't work with multiple plots, but I'm going to avoid it)

Comment: EDIT: I've created a custom plot hook altering the one in render_jekyll(), but the original has tons of non-exported function so I was not able to execute it at the end.

Comment: I think that this is going to be unanswered without @yihui-xie